# How am I supposed to be using filter_xss? Even though I'm using it, coder gives me an issue

Tags: php, drupal

> +269: [critical] Potential problem: drupal_set_message
>   http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_message/() only accepts
>   filtered text, be sure all !placeholders for $variables in t
>   http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t/() are fully sanitized using
>   check_plain http://api.drupal.org/api/function/check_plain/(),
>   filter_xss http://api.drupal.org/api/function/filter_xss/() or
>   similar.

Which pertains to this code:

```
      drupal_set_message(t('Batch complete!  View/Download !results', array(
        '!results' => filter_xss(l(t('simple results'), file_create_url($filename))),
      )), 'info');
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're using is under the 'DO NOT DO THESE THINGS' portion of [Dynamic or static links in translatable strings](http://drupal.org/node/322774). You need to change it to one of the approved methods. For reference:

```
<?php
  // DO NOT DO THESE THINGS
  $BAD_EXTERNAL_LINK = t('Look at Drupal documentation at !handbook.', array('!handbook' => '<a href="http://drupal.org/handbooks">'. t('the Drupal Handbooks') .'</a>'));
  $ANOTHER_BAD_EXTERNAL_LINK = t('Look at Drupal documentation at <a href="http://drupal.org/handbooks">the Drupal Handbooks</a>.');
  $BAD_INTERNAL_LINK = t('To get an overview of your administration options, go to !administer in the main menu.', array('!administer' => l(t('the Administer screen'), 'admin'));

  // Do this instead.
  $external_link = t('Look at Drupal documentation at <a href="@drupal-handbook">the Drupal Handbooks</a>.', array('@drupal-handbook' => 'http://drupal.org/handbooks'));
  $internal_link = t('To get an overview of your administration options, go to <a href="@administer-page">the Administer screen</a> in the main menu.', array('@administer-page' => url('admin')));
?>
```